# Passing a seq<string option> from F# to RProvider

Tags: f#

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283499/passing-a-seqfloat-option-from-f-to-rprovider) last week regarding `seq<float option>` values passed to RProvider.  I had hoped that I'd be able to apply the accepted answer there to other `option` types in F#.  Unfortunately, `NaN` is only applicable to `numeric` in R.

How can I convert a `None` string in F# to `NA` and pass to R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Option.toObj`.

For example:

```
let l1 = [ Some "x"; None; Some "y"] 

let l2 = l1 |> List.map (Option.toObj)
// val l2 : string list = ["x"; null; "y"]
```

And you can use `Option.toNullable` for number values, but it would convert to type `Nullable<float>`, and `None` would also be `null`. <s>For some reason this doesn't work the other way round:</s>

```
let l3 = l2 |> List.map (Option.ofObj)
// val l3 : string option list = [Some "x"; null; Some "y"]
```

I don't know if that's intended or a bug.

Edit : `Option.ofObj` does work properly. F# Interactive displays `None` as `null` when it is in a list for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your previous question is still applicable. You can use `null` to indicate a missing string value:

```
let optString = ["x"; null; "y"]

let testData5 =
    namedParams [
        "optString", optString;]
    |> R.data_frame
```

Gives me:

> val testData5 : SymbolicExpression =
>       optString
>   1         x
>   2       `<NA>`
>   3         y

You can convert the option string to just string list:

```
let optString2 = [Some "x"; None; Some "y"]
optString2 
    |> List.map (fun x -> match x with
                          | Some x -> x
                          | None -> null)
```