# Unable to reference 'FSharpOption<>' within C# project

Tags: f#

I am unable to reference `FSharpOption<>` within my C# PCL project targeting Xamarin.Android within Visual Studio 2015.

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JG2PPQBjTG0) that shows the steps of me attempting to resolve it.

The error I receive is the following:

> The type `FSharpOption<>` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>
> `FSharp.Core, Version=3.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`

**NOTE:**

My C# project DOES reference FSharp.Core. It is referencing the same FSharp.Core version that my F# projects are using:

```
some_path\packages\FSharp.Core.4.0.0.1\lib\portable-net45+monoandroid10+monotouch10+xamarinios10\FSharp.Core.dll
```

**Adding an App Config**

The app.config file that I placed in my Android client project is the same app.config file that I am using in my test project that's written in F#.

The app.config is the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                          culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.999.999.999" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone provide me guidance on the steps required to reference FSharp.Core functionality within my C# project?

**UPDATED**

I have another class that successfully references FSharp.Core within the same C# project:

```cs
static class Utility
{
    public static bool IsSome(this FSharpOption<string> option) => FSharpOption<string>.get_IsSome(option);
    public static bool IsNone(this FSharpOption<string> option) => FSharpOption<string>.get_IsNone(option);
}
```

The code above does not appear to cause any compile errors. Again, this file is in the same project as my other file that does cause errors.

The code that causes errors is the following:

```cs
using Microsoft.FSharp.Core;
// . . .
if (_viewModel.FamilySummary.IsSome()) {
}
```

**NOTE:**
The `using` statement for FSharp.Core appears to be ignored.

My viewmodel is hosted within an F# project inside Visual Studio.

Comment: You have probably done that but have you tried to Clean then Rebuild? Also, if you have control of the F# code, you could probably just avoid the problem entirely by using `Option.toObj` for the functions you're consuming from C#. It changes `string option` instances to `string` where `None` becomes `null`.

Comment: Is there an example of how to use it? I searched the spec and online and cannot find a code snippet.

Comment: it's part of F# 4 so unfortunately there is no documentation yet for it (it's absurd). The closest thing to an example i can find is [an earlier answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39338918/6150573). It's really straight forward, IMO.

Comment: [this is the pull request for that function](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/dsyme/cleanup/contribution/7672)

Comment: Just linked a video to my post showing the issue and me deleting folders.

Comment: I think the nuget path is wrong no? \portable-net45+monoandroid10+monotouch10+xamarinios10

Comment: I don't think so. The FSharp.Core.dll can be found in my bin directory of my Android project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue by adding the actual DLL file to my client project and then had my client reference that dll.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When I run into similar issue the solution was to uninstall FSharp.Core from both projects (the C# and the F# one) and then install it again but using the NuGet package manager for the Solution (not individually for each project).

So after removing FSharp.Core from both go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...

There search for FSharp.Core, tick all the projects you want to add the library to and select the version you want to add.

That solved this issue for me.

**Edit:** The other thing worth checking is that any library that is using FSharp.Core is actually using the same version as the one you installed.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I tried that and am still observing the same issue.

Comment: I recognize the error and know the above solved it for me. Unfortunately, I don't know why this solved it for me hence I don't know the real reason but only a procedure that solves some cases. Will investigate and update my post if I find anything.

Comment: Just updated my post as well. But reading your updated that won't help either. But your edit clarifies a lot. Let me spent some more time on that.

Comment: Just posted a bounty.

Comment: Just linked a video to my post showing the issue and me deleting folders.

Comment: I was working on that over the weekend but couldn't reproduce the issue. Will take a look at the video.

Answer (score 2):

After changing binding redirects in `app.config`, you may also need to delete the `obj` folder under the executable project folder.

For some reason an outdated config file can hang around in there and get copied to your bin folders, despite performing clean rebuilds.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What I didn't mention is that I deleted the bin and obj folder and rebuilt the solution. However, I keep receiving the same error.

Comment: Just linked a video to my post showing the issue and me deleting folders.

Comment: A post at the end of https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7278/xamarin-studio-not-loading-any-project-after-adding-fsharp-add-in-from-tools suggests adding the FSharp.Core binding redirect to the Xamarin msbuild.exe.config (and another comment suggests adding it to the xamarin studio exe config).

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm not using Xamarin Studio. I'm using Visual Studio.

Comment: What is the `Target F# runtime` value on the `Application` property page for the Portable library?

Comment: The version numbers of the `FSharp.Core` assembly in the portable subfolder of the nuget package seem to be 3.7.4 - there's some information about versions at https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html#fsharpcore-version-numbers

Comment: The target runtime on my PCL is 3.7.4.0. I looked at your link and F# 4.0 should support it.