# How to create a dataframe of multiple types with the RTypeProvider

Tags: r, f#, type-providers

It seems like the `RTypeProvider` can only handle `namedParams` of the same type.  Is this the case?

For example,

```
open RDotNet
open RProvider 

type foo = {
    Which: string
    Qty: float option
    }    

let someFoos = [{Which = "that"; Qty = Some 4.0}; {Which = "other"; Qty = Some 2.0}]

let thingForR = 
    namedParams [
        "which", someFoos |> List.map (fun x -> x.Which); 
        "qty", someFoos |> List.map (fun x -> x.Qty);
        ]
    |> R.data_frame
```

doesn't work as I get an error on the `x.Qty` saying

```
This expression was expected to have type 
  string
but here has type
  float option
```

If I reverse the order in the `thingForR` let, then I get the opposite error:

```
let thingForR = 
    namedParams [
        "qty", someFoos |> List.map (fun x -> x.Qty); 
        "which", someFoos |> List.map (fun x -> x.Which);
        ]
    |> R.data_frame
```

Here, the error on `x.Which` is

```
This expression was expected to have type
  float option
but here has type
  string
```

Can the dictionary in the `namedParams` not have different types?  If so, how can you create a data frame with different types in F# and pass them to R?

Comment: that's an F# error, welcome to strongly typed languages :-) you need to `box` it. But you will also have an issue with the option type. I'm not sure why but there is no converter for it. Let me search for the relevant answer first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to box the values inside the dictionary. That way they are all just object. So:

```
let thingForR = 
    namedParams [
        "which", box (someFoos |>  List.map (fun x ->  x.Which) ); 
        "qty", box  (someFoos |> List.map (fun x ->   x.Qty) |> List.map (Option.toNullable >> float));
        ]
    |> R.data_frame
```

gives me:

> val thingForR :
>   SymbolicExpression =   which qty
>   1  that   4
>   2 other  2

Please refer to your previous question on [float option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283499/passing-a-seqfloat-option-from-f-to-rprovider) to convert the `Option list` to `float list`. Also [string option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337732/passing-a-seqstring-option-from-f-to-rprovider/39338761#39338761) if necessary.

You can go through Deedle (if not for the option values):

```
let someFoos' = [{Which = "that"; Qty =  4.0}; {Which = "other"; Qty =  2.0}]
let df' = someFoos' |> Frame.ofRecords
df' |> R.data_frame
```

Comment: by the way the multiple maps and option conversion might look ugly but in reality if you use it a lot you'll end up defining helper functions for it.

Comment: Ah-ha!  Perfect.  Thanks.  And yes, converting the `float option` to `NaN` is necessary, as will be converting `string option` to `null`.  Just decided not to clutter things up with this question.