# Passing Options Into DataTable F#

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, f#, null

```
 let dataTable = new DataTable("mytable")
 dataTable.Columns.Add("bool_option_column") //typeof<bool option>
 dataTable.Columns.Add("int_column")
```

I have a boolean option column.  How do I allow null values to be stored in my SQL database when "myBooleanOption" is "None"?

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(
          myBooleanOption,
          myInt)
```

Note that the following is not an option (I need null values):

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(
          myBooleanOption |> Option.getValueOr false,
          myInt)
```

Here is something I have tried:

```
let nullToOpt = function
     | None -> new System.Nullable<_>()
     | Some x -> new System.Nullable<_>(x)

dataTable.Rows.Add(
              myBooleanOption |> nullToOpt,
              myInt)
```

To convert the option into a nullable value.  This doesn't work.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.  Thanks

Comment: `Option.toObj`?

Comment: I don't think "toObj" exists for options, but I will try to convert the option to an obj nonetheless.  Thank you!

Comment: `Option.toObj` exists in F# 4 (Visual Studio 2015).

Comment: `Option.toObj`, `Option.toNullable`, and `Option.ofNullable` exist starting with F# 4.0.

Comment: I didn't notice any of these.  This solved the problem - thanks

Comment: Does this not work for string options?

Comment: What do you mean by your last question? E.g. [String to option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337732/passing-a-seqstring-option-from-f-to-rprovider/39338761#39338761) or [String to option2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479934/how-to-create-a-dataframe-of-multiple-types-with-the-rtypeprovider/39480714#39480714).

Comment: I mean this doesn't work:  my_string_option |> Option.toNullable

Comment: String is a reference type, and cannot be a Nullable type in .NET, it can of course be null. So you cannot use it like a nullable float. But if you need to pattern match a string option you can do it like in the answers above.